# How to Create a 3D Shaky Camera Effect in GML

Tags: gml, 3dcamera

I am currently working on a project in GameMaker:S.
I want to know how I would create an effect where the 3D camera bobs around, as if it is being held by somebody with unsteady hands? I've been trying to figure something out for a couple of days now.
Cheers.

Comment: *I've been trying to figure something out for a couple of days now.*  Please share what that is.

Comment: Well, I've tried a few variations on the game randomly generating a point, moving to that point with an ease-in-out, and when it's close enough, generating a new point to go to. Generating point is easy enough, but the ease-in-out part is where I've failed. Obviously there could be a better solution to trying to create this effect that I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

1.Maybe you can create an invisible object, edit it so it can randomly teleport or move to locations and then make the view[0] to follow it.
or you can create a path for the object to follow.

2.You can create a variable like; `x = irandom(-100,100)` and set the view to follow it.

3.Use the most foolish method: instead of camera, let everything else move so that the player things camera is moving. You can do this by randomly moving background, objects etc.

Comment: I'm using a 3D camera, by the way. I'd like to roll with a version method 2 -- randomly generating the camera's rotation velocity -- but then there's the question of how to stop the camera from panning too far in any direction. Perhaps you could make the random equation add/subtract the X/Y position from the random generation range. Do you think that might work?

Comment: maybe you can set an alarm then use it to subtract velocity randomly. or look at the documents about the view, in help. that might help you out.